# PowerShell, programmatically set TaskBar colour

Tags: powershell, taskbar, user-interface

I have some home servers that I access, and also Windows Sandbox on my main system. Sometimes I lose track of which RDP session I am in or the Sandbox when I am in full-screen sessions and it occurred to me that the Taskbar is the thing that is almost always visible, so I would like to run something in PowerShell that will set prominent colours for the Taskbar, e.g. leave my main system the default black in Dark Mode, then have blue shading for my file-server in the basement, and then green shading for my Windows Sandbox, so that it will be very obvious where I am. How can I do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

To change the taskbar color :

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Colors*
- Set "Choose your default Windows mode" to "Dark"
  (the following does not work with "Light")
- Set "Choose your colour" to "Custom"
- Use the color picker to choose a color and click Done
- Check "Start, taskbar, and action center"

The taskbar should now change to the custom color.

For more details with screenshots see
[How to Change the Taskbar Color in Windows 10](https://www.lifewire.com/change-taskbar-color-in-windows-10-5180157).

---

If you wish to automate the above changes, I can see two methods :

1. Create an AutoHotKey script that can run Settings and do all
   the clicks for you.
2. Do the registry changes yourself.

For the second method, I have traced the Settings app and I found
that the changes are all done inside the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent`, where some of the values are not easy to understand.

I tested, and exporting this registry key as a `.reg`
file conserves the color.

Therefore I suggest changing the registry to all the colors you
need, exporting this key for each one. Executing the matching
`.reg` file will then set the color with an almost immediate
effect.

If you need to enable showing color on your start, taskbar,
and action center, this is again done in the registry at
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`,
item `ColorPrevalence` which is `1` for On and `0` for Off.

You may program these registry changes in PoerShell, but executing
the `.reg` files is just as easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, but I was specifically looking for a way to *automate* this in PowerShell, otherwise I would have to do it every time that I startup a new Windows Sandbox (since that is a clean system every time). If I can do it in PowerShell, then I can put that into my startup script so that the Sandbox always starts up with that setting applied.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @YorSubs: Now that I know exactly what you need, I added more information on automating this process.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I'm going to try and work out some PowerShell commands based on this... I'll build a few test-case examples and post them here.

Comment: There exist Registry to PowerShell converters - [random example](https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/registry-to-powershell-converter/).